# Least rank of a definable R

Tags: set-theory

The set of real numbers can be defined in many ways, including by Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences. The different definitions will give different ranks for the underlying set. There exists a set S, of rank w+2 such that S can be equipped with an addition, multiplication, and order relation such that S can be considered as a candidate for "the" set of real numbers. But what is the least rank, meaning the least ordinal, of a set S that can be defined in ZFC without parameters, and whose addition, multiplication, and order relations can also be defined without parameters, such that S is the underlying set of "the" field of real numbers? I am sorry if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a different convention for defining rank than most texts used (which causes a different of 1). Anyway to be clear as to what definition of rank I am using, I will define it here: The rank of $x$ is the least $\alpha$ such that $x \in V_{\alpha + 1}$. Note that the rank $\emptyset$ is $0$ under this definition.

Note that if your definition of the rank of $x$ is the least $\alpha$ such that $x \in V_\alpha$, then the rank of $\emptyset$ is $1$ and limit ordinals can never be the rank of any element. Again if this is your definition of rank, you will just need to shift everything by $1$.

The Dedekind cut definition of $\mathbb{R}$ will give a definition of the reals of rank $\omega + 1$. (In your post, you stated that you know of a definition of $\mathbb{R}$ of rank $\omega + 2$. I suspect you are using the same example, but with the latter definition of rank.)

I claim that $\omega + 1$ is the minimal possible definition essentially by cardinality considerations. This is because all elements of $V_\omega$ is finite. So $\mathbb{R} \notin V_\omega$. Since $V_{\omega}$ is countable, all elements of $V_{\omega + 1}$ is countable. Again, $\mathbb{R} \notin V_{\omega + 1}$. Thus if $\mathbb{R} \in V_{\alpha}$, then $\alpha \geq \omega + 2$. (Using my definition of rank) the rank of $\mathbb{R}$ must be greater than or equal to $\omega + 1$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It's not what the least possible rank for $\Bbb R$; but rather what is the least possible rank for $\Bbb R$ along with its field structure to be definable without parameters. In the case of using $\mathcal P(\omega)$, the field structure is not particularly apparent from the structure of the set, whereas continuing in the usual manner of constructing $\Bbb{Z,Q,R}$ we end up at rank $\omega+6$ more or less, and the definition there uses no parameters since it stems from the arithmetic structure of $\omega$ which is definable without parameters itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, coding pairs of reals as reals is probably not the OP is looking for. But I think an optimal bound can still be obtained. If you insist that the multiplication must consist of a set of order triples of the actual objects defined to be $\mathbb{R}$, then depending on how ordered pairs are defined, there is lowest possible rank among order pairs of objects defined to be reals. Probably the sensible way of doing this will reach the lowest possible rank.

Comment: William, there are flat pairing functions which do not increase the rank. So we can assume that the operations are defined on the same rank as the real numbers, and the structure $\langle\Bbb R,+,\cdot,\leq\rangle$ is defined on the same rank as those sets as well. Now, we know that there are such sets which turn $V_{\omega+1}$ into $\Bbb R$, but are those definable without parameters? I don't know. It seems to me that the answer is negative, and the least rank would still be something like $\omega+6$ or so.

Comment: I think both of you misunderstand my question. The question was the least rank of a set S for which all components of the structure (S, +, *, <) is definable without parameters.

Comment: @user107952 If you only want the least rank of $S$ such that $(S, +, *, <)$ is definable without parameters, then my answer will work for you. Asaf's interpretation is the least rank of $(S, +, *, <)$ such that ...

Comment: But how to prove that the dedekind cut definition of reals has rank w+1? Is this covered in some set theory textbook?

Comment: @user107952 Hint: What are the possible rank of rational numbers? Dedekind cuts are sets of rational. So what is the rank of a Dedekind cut? What is the rank of the set of all cuts?